# Detect by code the width of the Arabic letter which is a type of path or compound path in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: javascript, python, adobe, adobe-illustrator

In Adobe Illustrator I have many paths like arabic words in ottoman calligraphy layout, and the source of these paths is not a outlined text but a path.
So I need to detect by code (javascript, python, VBscript, ...) the width of each arabic character in that path because I'm going to cut and separate each character in the path.
The cutting code depends on determining the location of the cutting in the path, which is equal to the starting location of the path, and add to it the width of the letter that I will cut now.
Note: I know in advance every letter in this path through previously preserved data. I only know what the letter is, and I do not know what is its size that changes from one word to another because it is a calligraphy layout and not a fixed font.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks rather like a typical task for neural network. Not the average JS script. And the main obstacle for neural algorithm is you have to provide thousands of correct examples first. Not sure if this is the solution you're asking.

Comment: Using a neural network is my last option, I'll look first if there is any way for my request, maybe it works in paths direction and each letter has a specific direction or any other methodology

Comment: Could you provide the ai/eps file? If the word it's a compound path there can be a straightforward simply solution indeed. It depends on how exactly this compound path is constructed inside.

Comment: download it from this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1woXam_I2WPe0kTkBPsbZ3LN39Od3k8Jo/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Sorry for delay. I just looked the paths in the file closely and I see no way to guess how to split them into characters automatically via a script. (

Comment: Don't worry,  thank you @YuriKhristich for your interest